# Splash Screen won't hide

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a SplashScreen to my Application but i'm facing an issue:
The SplashScreen loads and just that... it doesn't take me to the Main Activity.
Here's the SplashScreenActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);


    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StartAnimations();
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

    }
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Where do you **finish** the splash Activity and **start** the main Activity?

Comment: so you are using your splash screen only for animation I guess. After that animation you need to finish splash screen activity and launch your main activity. Main activity won't load unless you start it.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Any idea on how to start my Main activity?

Comment: @jvrodrigues already answered that... If you don't want to put a delay then see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this after your animation...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Your code gets me straight into the app, like it skips the SplashScreenActivity. Should i add a timer?

Comment: Its not skipping the splash screen but its too fast. Use a timer for the duration you want to show the splash screen.

Comment: seems that all i had to do was to add a timer, thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your startAnimations method:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {    
      Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class); //assuming your main ctivity is called that
      startActivity(intent);
      SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

}, 3000); //assuming you want for the splashscreen to be displayed for 3 seconds.
```

Comment: (MainActivity.class, this);  <- it says: "Cannot resolve constructor Intent (java.lang.Class<com.alec_myd.www.alec.MainActivity>,java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Woops! I made a mistake there. Edited it try now.

Comment: "Cannot resolve constructor Intent (java.lang.Class<com.alec_myd.www.alec.MainActivity>,<com.alec_myd.www.alec SplashScreenActivity") i have no idea what to do...i can finish the SplashScreenActivity just by adding this at the end: SplashScreenActivity.this.finish(); but how do i start my main activity?

Comment: It's late and I'm very tired. .. try with the last edit.